# How to pass registered icon in sql

Tags: sql, icons

I'm trying to copy paste registered icon from word to sql console. It just dumps a weird icon on sql console. How can I pass that icon? © works fine.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're on Windows, have you tried typing Alt+0169?

Comment: Alt + 0174….. ®….registered ­ trademark symbol

Answer (score 0):

Alt + 0174….. ®….registered ­ trademark symbol

This allows you to add the trademark symbol.